# Image Upload Servlet not working in Chrome, but works in other browsers

Tags: java, image, servlets, google-chrome

I have tested this servlet and it works well, except in Google Chrome it jsut doesn't display image. What could be wrong in this example code that makes Chrome not to display image?

http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html

Comment: How about adding some sample code so that we dont ASS|U|ME things? ;-)

Comment: Works fine here. Which of the two examples are you talking about? What exactly did you change in the code?

Comment: First example... i will check what changes are made to code ...

Comment: I recommend to NOT make any changes in the code and retest it.

Comment: Apparently problem is related to jCrop javascript, but when I change image url to web folder, it jcrop works fine, so there must be somethings in jcrop settings/javascript that makes it not to show up

Comment: OK, good luck hunting it down. You may want to delete this question as it's not relevant anymore.

Comment: Apparently image was loaded in other browsers before jcrop was initialized, but not in chrome

Comment: Just initialize it during `window.onload` (or if you're using jQuery, `$(document).ready()`). I would be surprised if the jcrop guys didn't mention it in their documentation ..

Comment: It was inside document on ready, but that apparently doesn't mean that images are loaded, so i had to put $(".image-selector").load(fucntion(){ ... init jrop here ... });

Comment: It may be worth to report it to the jcrop guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the following line was missing:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(image.length()));
```

Some browsers may namely be picky on that.